# Parsing JSON file and converting into csv file using jq

Tags: shell, jq

I am trying to parse my data and convert them into multiple **csv** files, according to the section.

#### Sample JSON

```
{
    "content": [
    {
        "Title": "abc",
        "brand": "xyz",
        "size": "5 g",
        "date": "2019-01-01",
        "details": {
            "Temperature": [
            {
                "value": "90",
                "chracterstics":"Normal"
            },
            {
                "value":"100",
                "chracterstics":"high"
            },

            {
                "value":"80",
                "chracterstics":"low"
            }
            ],

            "certifications": [
            {
                "value": "based",
                "chracterstics":"pass"
            },

            {
                "value": "50",
                "chracterstics":"failed"
            }
            ]
        },

         "formats": {
            "city": "NYC",
            "id": "007",
            "manufacture":""
            },
        "innerDetails": [
        {
            "contains": "abc",
            "panel":"xyz",
            "values":[
                {
                    "name":"abc",
                    "value":"10"
                },
                {
                    "name":"xyz",
                    "value":"20"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
]
}
```

I am trying to put the content data into one **csv** file, Temperature data into second **csv** file, certifications into third, formats and inner details data in other separate file.

I have tried the below approach, but getting "Cannot index array with string "brand"" error.

```
jq -r '.[]|[.Title,.brand,.size,.date]|@csv' $jsonfile > sample.csv.
```

I was trying on the same line with other sections, but getting the same error.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The JSON isn't completely valid. Paste it in https://jsonlint.com/ and see the errors

Comment: I am able to get the result using jq -r '.content[]|[.Title,.brand,.size,.date]|@csv' $jsonfile > sample.csv, but I would like to know that is there any way to get the details on the basis of heading. As, I have very huge json file and the file is somewhat similar to the sample file. for e.g contents details using content heading,innerDetails by using innerDetails heading, formats details using format heading.

Comment: To get this json to parse, "content" needs to be put in quotes, and "}] }" needs to be added to the end of this snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, it might be best to handle each set of data in a separate invocation of jq.
This seems reasonable here given that each invocation of jq is quite fast, and it seems you will only need a small number of such invocations.

The Temperature and certifications data are uniform in the JSON input and so can be handled in a loop such as:

```
for field in Temperature certifications ; do
    echo $field ::
    jq --arg field "$field" -r '
      .content[].details | .[$field][]
      | [.value, .characteristics] | @csv' input.json > output.$field.csv
done
```

(This assumes of course that the JSON is valid, and that "certifications" has been spelled correctly.)

### Adding "content"-specific columns

```
for field in Temperature certifications ; do
    echo $field ::
    jq --arg field "$field" -r '.content[]
      | [.Title, .brand] as $columns
      | .details | .[$field][]
      | ($columns + [.value, .characteristics]) | @csv
    ' so-multiple-csv-files.json > tmp.output.$field.csv
done
```

Comment: I am able to get the result by above but is it possible to have the "Title" and "brand" as the first two columns in both temperature and certifications related files?                            I tried to put [.Title, .brand, .value, .characteristics] in above code but I am getting blank for both the columns.

Comment: Thank you @peak for your support. it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use map:

`$jq -r '.[] | map(.Title), map(.brand), map(.size), map(.date) | @csv' yourfile.json > sample.csv`

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, but I want some generic loop structure for details field. because that contains arrays like Temperature and certifications in large number with "value" and "characteristics" as their values and I want to put Temperature,certifications etc in their respective csv files.